# Matlab: delete rows based on a sequence of number ine one column

Tags: matlab, row, sequence

I have a matrix with 2 columns. I would like to delete rows based on a sequence of numbers in column 2. 
For example:

```
Data = [1 2
        3 4
        5 4
        6 2
        7 0
        8 2]
```

then delete rows if sequence in column 2 is 4 4 2.
so I would end up with:

```
Data = [1 2
        7 0
        8 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's add some data to Data, to show this on two `[4 4 2]` sequences:

```
Data =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     4
     6     2
     7     0
     8     2
     9     2
     7     4
     1     4
     0     2
     4     0
     3     2
```

Now, this should do the job and delete the rows that include the sequence `[4 4 2]` in the second column:

```
Seq=[4 4 2];       % sequence to delete rows according to
Data(bsxfun(@plus,findstr(Data(:,2)',Seq)',(0:length(Seq)-1)),:)=[]

Data =

     1     2
     7     0
     8     2
     9     2
     4     0
     3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Adiel is greate, however if the range of numbers contained in `Data` is beyond the values that can be represented by character strings you can use this method:

```
Data = [1 2
        3 4
        5 4
        6 2
        7 0
        8 2]
Seq = [4 4 2]
```

Create a matrix that shows equality of Seq with elements of Data:

```
r = size(Data, 1);
n = numel(Seq);
idx = bsxfun(@eq, Data(:,2), Seq);
idx =

   0   0   1
   1   1   0
   1   1   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
```

We then should reshape `idx` to size `[r+1,n]`:

```
idx2 = false(r+1, n);
idx2(idx) = true;
idx2 =

   0   1   0
   1   1   1
   1   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   0
```

Now if a sequence of `[4 4 2]` is contained in `Data` all elements of each row of `idx2` will be 1. So we should find such rows.

```
    f = find(all(idx2, 2));
    f = 

       2
```

So indexes of beginning of each sequence is found . To find other elements we add `0:n-1` to `f` .

```
idx3 = bsxfun(@plus, f, 0:n-1);
idx3 =

   2   3   4
```

Remove elements:

```
Data(idx3, :) = [];
Data =

   1   2
   7   0
   8   2
```